# htaccess Redirect 403 add folder to path if not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have this url - that is working

```
http://pic.site.com/images/nofeymata/102.jpg
```

and i have in my app this url - that i get 403 error

```
 http://pic.site.com/nofeymata/102.jpg
```

i need a way "add" `images` to the path only if i get 403 eroor

my htaccess lock like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^width=\d+&height=\d+&image=(.*)
RewriteRule ^ %1? 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} imageget\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [NC,L]

#disallow access to other php files
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} .+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

so when my app seach for this url

```
http://pic.site.com/nofeymata/102.jpg
```

and get 403 wil redrict to

```
http://pic.site.com/images/nofeymata/102.jpg
```

this part `/nofeymata/102.jpg` is random can be any folder and file

i have tryed

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images[NC]
RewriteRule ^ /images%{REQUEST_URI} [R=403,L]
```

this is working but when i query this

```
http://pic.site.com/images/nofeymata/102.jpg
```

i get

```
http://pic.site.com/images/images/nofeymata/102.jpg
```

i cant figre it out, thanks!

Comment: What would be the purpose of that? Why would you want to redirect, instead of outputting the error code under the requested URL? With this, you will prevent clients from properly associating the 403 status code with the actual URL.

Comment: its just cdn for images

Answer (score 0):

i add this

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
```

and in the 404.php file

```
<?php

$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$http = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]."/images".$url ;
header("Location: http://".$http); /* Redirect browser */
?>
```

and its working now perfect good sulotion